# Hyper-V not connecting to Virtual Machine in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I have installed Hyper-V manager on Windows 10 pro and have connected to the server which is hosting all virtual machines. By using the `Connect to server`, I am able to see all the virtual machines. Their state's are `running` and their status is empty. I try to connect to them but I can't, and ideas? and no error message.

Comment: Have you got any further with this?

Comment: It works and does not work = ( . So I made sure that the bios had virtualization enabled. And it seems to have a glitch with RDP console. Some days it works after restart and some days it won't. Sorry.

Comment: I seem to have less issues if I start the machine AFTER I connect, i.e. I see the "starting machine", messages, etc.  If I start it "right-click >> Start" and then connect afterwards, tickets!! - mostly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue initially after I set up a VM yesterday, but got it going after some fiddling around. Unfortunately I can't remember what I did that made the difference though! I think it was related to security. However this morning, after connecting to a different network, it failed again.

My eventual solution: I turned off the Hyper-V features in "Turn Windows features on or off", restarted, then turned them back on again and restarted again. Now everything works fine. Hopefully it will continue to work when I move networks again - will comment here if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing it by regedit. You will have to go to the - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services and there you will have to change the value to 0. If it's not working then try using RDP wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with a local Hyper-V instance on a Windows 10 client while working outside of the office network. In our domain environment, all RDP connections go through an RD Broker. Since I did not have access to the RD Broker, Hyper-V would try to communicate to the RD Broken then fail to connect to the VM's console. I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the RD Proxy to our RD Broker within the registry.

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\UseProxy = 0

My issue may be unique, but it's worth noting during the troubleshooting process of this console connection issue.

Also, if your computer and user account are governed by GPO, your registry tweak on "UseProxy" will probably be reverted.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state.

Answer (score 0):

that works,but I needed to change it a bit.
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services

then i create a new value key UseProxy = 0.

Comment: What works?  This looks like it might be a comment about Derek Preston's answer.

Comment: It is not exactly a comment to Derek Prestons`s answer as this one points to a different location of regedit that did work for me. Derek`s answer did not work for me.